# How to access page history (page updates) through Notion API

Tags: api

I don't seem to find an answer to this anywhere, including the Notion [official API docs](https://developers.notion.com/), so here is my question:

How do you request a page history thorough the Notion API. The stuff that is available by pressing the "Updates" button in the app UI

[image]

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to do that through the official API.

We will just have to wait and see if Notion decides to add this functionality to their API (see https://developers.notion.com/page/changelog).